# sparse_image_warp in Tensorflow doesn't work?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing

I want to apply a warp to an image specified by the source and destination locations of a (potentially small) number of control points in deep learning framework. And I thought the function '[tf.contrib.image.sparse_image_warp](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/sparse_image_warp)' can do exactly what I want. But after I tried, the warped image didn't look good.

More specifically, I want to warp the source image to destination image by face landmarks. So, I used the following code:

```
warped_image, dense_flows = sparse_image_warp(source_image, source_image_landmarks, dest_image_landmarks)
```

And the results are here:

source image with landmark:
[image]

dest image with landmark:
[image]

warped result:
[image]

desired result generated by other method:
[image]

**Am I using the function in wrong way? Or the function can't realize my need?**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But actually, that is exactly what I thought when I first saw the warped result. And I also tired it (swap the parameters), but the warped result was even worse. @Shai

Comment: @Shai: Thank you soooo much!!! Problem solved by using y-x. (I have wasted for two days on it...)

Answer (score 1):

Pay close attention to [`tf.contrib.image.sparse_image_warp`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/sparse_image_warp), you need to supply the control points (lfacial landmarks in your example) in **`y`-`x`** coordinate rather than `x`-`y`.